# Receiving call intent in broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I want to get the called number in android but When I start the outgoing call it fails I am using broadcast receiver and register it in service to keep listen if activity not in focus here is my code.

Menifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.vampirepc.androidservice" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />


            </action>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".MyService" />


    <receiver
        android:name="com.example.vampirepc.androidservice.OutgoingReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
</manifest>
```

BroadcastReceiver Class

```
  @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Toast.makeText(ctx,
            "Inside broadcast",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

    Toast.makeText(context, "Outgoing call catched: " + phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}
```

Service

```
  @Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Service created",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    try {


        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL");

        OutgoingReceiver myReceiver = new OutgoingReceiver();
        registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);


    } catch (Exception e) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Exception is "+String.valueOf(e),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }



}
```

Comment: There is no need to register the receiver at run time in your case, just define it inside the manifest.

Comment: Still not working when i dial a number Application stopped working

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Comment: It does not stop the application when I remove all code inside  onReceive method.

Comment: I think problem is with the Toast.

Comment: Try removing the toast lines and logging the number instead.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this
[Phone state Broadcaster](https://gist.github.com/Mariovc/d2add6a150d31af049953461b6ab9408)

Answer (score 0):

Please add the permission in the top ,this helped me

```
      ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.vampirepc.androidservice" >

    android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />


                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver
            android:name="com.example.vampirepc.androidservice.OutgoingReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

  <service android:name=".MyService" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission 
    </manifest>
```

Comment: Please refer this link https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-studio-tutorial-an-app-to-track-outgoing-calls/

Answer (score 0):

Have you realized in this line:

```
Toast.makeText(ctx,
        "Inside broadcast",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

You used ctx instead of context.

Answer (score 0):

Thank to all i have solved the problem my self I was using incorrect context in toaster the correct  onReceive is.
I was using ctx which was initialize.

```
Context ctx;


   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Toast.makeText(context, "this is not shown"     , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



    String phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

    Toast.makeText(context, "Outgoing call catched: " + phoneNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


 }
```